# Android app language localization trough json

Tags: android, json, localization

Lets take for example, that you need to apply language localization trough a setting in the app itself, can i do it by getting strings from json? Like i get json link that contains different countries, and those countries contain entire translations. Is it possible to do it like that?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible

```
String lang = json.getstring("countrycode");//EN for English
public void setLocale(String lang) { 
  myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
  Resources res = getResources(); 
  DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
  Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
  conf.locale = myLocale; 
  res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
  Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
  startActivity(refresh); 
  finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with the localization tools available out of the box in Android.

If you want to achieve something like this, you have to implement in on your own or look for a library that does it for you.

As a suggestion - properly localizing an app far more complex than it seems, so I really don't think you should try and bypass the built in way of doing it.